# Dapper splitOn not working

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010, dapper

I'm trying to run a MS Access query with Dapper. I keep receiving the following error message: *When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id*

This is the code I'm using:

```
IEnumerable<BalanceHeader> balanceHeaders = 
    _connection.Query<BalanceHeader, Currency, BalanceHeader>(
        "GetFullBalanceHeaders", 
        (header, currency) => 
        {
            header.Currency = currency;
            return header;
        }, 
        splitOn: "IsoCode", 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT BalanceHeader.Reference
,  BalanceHeader.ReferenceCount
,  BalanceHeader.GroupName
,  Currency.IsoCode
,  Currency.ExchangeRate
FROM [Currency]
INNER JOIN BalanceHeader ON Currency.IsoCode = BalanceHeader.IsoCode;
```

The splitOn param has cleary been set so what else am I doing wrong? Or is this an issue with MS Access?

Comment: Does it work if you just use the sql query instead of the stored procedure?  Maybe write old style ADO.Net code with the stored procedure to see what column names are returned in the data reader?

Comment: I tried it with the SQL query instead of the stored procedure and it made no difference.

Comment: That makes me think that Access is not returning the column names from your query in the way you would expect, specifically that `Currency.IsoCode` is not returning as `IsoCode`.  Have you successfully used Dapper with Access before?  With the same connection provider?

Comment: Haven't tried this specific case with Access yet. If I retrieve the column names with plain old ADO.net I can see that they are exactly what you would expect. IsoCode = IsoCode. Issue with Access?

Comment: Dapper just uses ADO.Net under the hood, so if that's what your seeing then I'm at a loss.  Hopefully one of the guys that work on Dapper will see this question and help you out.  Although another option would be to get the Dapper source and debug into it to see what the issue is.

Comment: So it turns out that I'm using Dapper version 1.25. The latest version is 1.38 and with that it's working. Now testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the version of Dapper from 1.25 to 1.38 has fixed the issue!